# How can I find the number of real roots?

Tags: polynomials, roots

How can I find the number of real roots of the polynomial
$$P=X^4+2X^3-6X^2+X+1$$?

Comment: HINT: Descartes rule of signs

Comment: I tried with Decartes and according to this rule I'd have only one positive root and one negative? I don't know this rule very well.

Comment: Sketch the graph, maybe? By computing the derivative and double derivative of the function.

Comment: At least you have identified a topic (Descartes's rule of signs) worth learning more about.  A certain amount of work is necessary to answer such problems.  Don't be shy about sharing what you are doing, as it is better to catch yourself in a mistake than give Readers the impression you just want someone to do your thinking for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Descartes' rule of signs :

The polynomial $P(x) = x^4 + 2x^3 - 6x^2 + x + 1$ has two sign changes between the second, third and fourth terms (the sequence of pairs of successive signs is ++, −, ++), therefore it has exactly two positive roots.

The polynomial $P(-x) = x^4 - 2x^3 - 6x^2 - x + 1$ has two sign changes between the first, second, fourth and fifth terms again (the sequence of pairs of successive signs is +-, -, -+), therefore it has exactly two negative roots.

Finally, summing up, the polynomial $P(x) = x^4 + 2x^3 - 6x^2 + x + 1$ has **four** real roots.

Comment: And how do you rule out [the case when $P$ has no positive roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs#Descartes.27_rule_of_signs)?

Comment: Sorry @G.Sassatelli, I just multiplied by -1 and did the same method, corrected it now, was in a hurry. No need to rule out the case when P has no positive roots since 1) We have already proven the existence of them 2)  Using Descartes' rule of signs on $g(x)$ gives the number of positive roots $x_{i}$ of $g$, and since $g(x) = f(-x)$ it gives the number of positive roots $(-x_i)$ of $f$, which is the same as the number of negative roots $x_{i}$of $f$.

Comment: I don't know who that "we" in (1) is, since clearly he is not the person who asked the question: his doubt is "how many real roots dose $P$ have", therefore "the answer is $4$" cannot be a hypothesis.

Comment: It is not a hypothesis, it is exactly and firmly proven by using the Descartes' rule of signs, exactly as the method presumes.

Comment: Descarte's rule of sign says that, if $n$ is the number of changes of sign in the sequence of coefficients of a polynomial, then the number of positive roots is a number $0\le m\le n$ such that $n-m$ is even. For instance, for the polynomial $x^2-x+1$ the number of positive roots is $0$, which is in fact $2-2$. Similar thing happens for $$(x^2-\sqrt3 x+1)(x^2+\sqrt 3x+1)=(x^4-x^2+1)$$

Comment: Or, for instance, a closed cousin of the polynomial in the OP: $$x^4+2x^3-2x^2+x+1$$ It has no positive roots and exactly two negative roots.

Comment: The actual solution is to use Sturms theorem instead of Descartes rule of signs https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem